# How to migrate from MySQL to PostgreSQL

Tags: 6, migrations, database

I need to know how to migrate my Drupal 6 database from MySQL to PostgreSQL. I also like to hear first hand experience tales about actual migrations.

P.S. I found [this](http://groups.drupal.org/node/15793) drupal-mysql2pgsql.pl migration script which apparently does the job but I could not make use of it due to the fact that I dont' know how to make " passwordless account in both databases". There is also [this guide](http://www.thaitux.info/book/export/html/679) (in Thai) which adds credentials to database connection lines in the script. But it did not help either, as I could not connect to Postgresql. I know very little about Postgresql and may have had some silly mistake. Any through explanation/tutorial on this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Module [DBTNG Migrator](http://drupal.org/project/dbtng_migrator) will do it.

Comment: The module is for Drupal 7.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Drupal 7, there's a sandbox project called [Portable Databse Dump](http://drupal.org/sandbox/damz/1174672) that purports to allow you to dump a Drupal site from one database backend to another.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm using Drupal 6.

Answer (score 3):

I have an experience with both postgres and mysql sites under high load, and I don't think migration can be done for performance reasons. Both engines are good, and final success depends on ability of your DB admins to tune up DB installation for specific site.
Another point: to boost performance, you choose tools to minimize need in DB queries (boost/memcache/varnish), so you end up with relatively low weight of DB processing.

Answer (score 1):

Check all of the modules that you use or ever may want to use on your site.  Not all contrib modules are database agnostic.  I can't think of any off the top of my head, but I have run into modules that use MySQL-only functions.

Comment: Do you think the effort to migrate to Postgresql worth at all?

Comment: I don't consider the risk of a module not working with PostgreSQL worth taking when working on projects for a client.

Comment: Assuming that all modules work in Postgresql, will you suggest the migration, performance-wise?

Comment: Because of this complication, we don't deploy it, so I don't have real-world metrics to compare to.